# Creating multirow table headers

Tags: vaadin

I have a table where my column headers are set with the following instruction :

```
table.setColumnHeader
```

I wonder how can I create multilevel table headers like [on this page](http://www.bls.gov/xg_shells/ro5xg01.htm)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Vaadin 6.7.3, this is currently not possible using the stock Vaadin table component.

There is a Trac issue raised for changing this for Vaadin 7. See https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/900369 for more details.

Depending on your requirements, you could hide the table component's header and try to simulate the header (by using a HorizontalLayout, generating your own headers and listening to column resize events); alternatively, you could simply generate your own HTML `<table></table>` and assign it to a label component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to inject some HTML in a table header ?

Comment: @MorningGlory Into the Vaadin table component header? No. Into an HTML table, certainly!

Answer (score 1):

In Vaadin7 you can set the table header height dynamically by adding following CSS rule to your theme:

```
  .v-table-header-wrap {
    height: auto;
  }
```

The only think is that the column separator is not set to 100% of the header row height ...

Answer (score 0):

A look into the TreeTable component may help you : 
[Vaadin sampler](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#TreeTableBasic)

Regards,
Éric.

Comment: Well, the TreeTable concerns the content. I'm asking on how can I include multiple rows in a table header ? Please refer to my link above.

Answer (score 0):

To make a header only of a table use setPageLength(0);  this will eliminate the table body and show only the header.
Then create another table with a header and your data and combine these 2 in a layout :)
It's a cool trick, be sure to match the ratio's of first header with the second's table header.