# How to set multi-line header for Vaadin Table?

Tags: vaadin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating multirow table headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791269/creating-multirow-table-headers)

How to Vaadin set multi-line header? I would like to set up a two rows of the table head
like:-

```
<pre>
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Name              |                          | 
    ---------------------------|          age             |          sex 
        F name   |    Lname    |                          |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible in Vaadin Table.

EDIT: See Charles' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800594/270910) for a workaround. Another way is to modify the client-side implementation of the Table component and add support for those multi-line headers, but it's not trivial.

Comment: Thank you ！  That's so terrible！

Comment: And I want development this  multi-line of the table head ，Could you give some advise？

Comment: I edited my answer to add info how to possible solve the problem.

Comment: you could add a line of header by using a table with setPageLength(0) which will eliminate the table's body, and combine it with another table and add it to a layout. also you should match the ratios of first header with second header columns.:)